# Normalize screwed git history

Tags: git

I was working on a few features and had to do few rebases. Tho something went wrong and now there are lots of duplicate commits with same date and changes but different hashes.
How could I restore it?

[image: history]

Comment: "_I was working on a few features and had to do few rebases. Tho something went wrong_" What commands did you run, what was the output, etc....

Comment: Is there a distant version of the branch, before the local rebases happened?

Comment: Most probably there are some branches/tags which are sustain old version of rebased branch. For example you have rebased pushed branch and didn't to forceful push yet (to discard on server old version of branch). To fix it we need more details what have you done with your repository.

Comment: Can you see a good starting point in `git reflog`? If so, would you be willing to go back and try again?

Comment: Note that the hash isn't important to the integrity of the *commit*, but rather the *whole history*. "_lots of duplicate commits with same date and changes but different hashes_" - this isn't a _problem_, but it is untidy... you could probably remove the duplicates without affecting the working content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Interactive rebasing.

> **Interactive rebasing**  gives you the opportunity to alter commits as they are moved to the new branch. This is even more powerful than an automated rebase, since it offers complete control over the branch’s commit history. Typically, this is used to clean up a messy history before merging a feature branch into master

Since I don't know which state you're trying to restore, I will assume that you want just to remove the duplicate commits. The way to go with it will be to rebase in an interactive mode `rebase -i base_branch`, you will get something like that:

```
pick d62629a Add custom image
pick 3fe3b9c Add custom image
pick 2e8602b Refactor ...
pick 1b0d561 Add custom image
```

You'll then just have to change the action `pick` to `drop` or simply `d` for the commits you want to remove like so:

```
pick d62629a Add custom image
d 3fe3b9c Add custom image
pick 2e8602b Refactor ...
d 1b0d561 Add custom image
```

That's one way of doing it.